# Get price data at PancakeSwap

Tags: python, cryptography, token, nft, pancakeswap

Hi i've met a problem with getting data from pancakeswap. Are there any endpoinds or subgraph apis or smthing else to get price data from PancakeSwap

I've tried to find endpoints or using weird subgraps but nothing works

I'd like to get price data of every token in pancake

Comment: what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2):

You can get real-time PancakeSwap data using Bitquery's [PancakeSwap API](https://bitquery.io/blog/pancake-swap-dex-apis). It can provide real time and historical PancakeSwap **trades**, **prices** and **liquidity pool** details.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Moralis API to do that, they offer `getTokenPrice` API that indexes multiple DEXs on multiple chain, one of it is of course Pancakeswap.

You can try it out right here as long as you have the address of the token https://docs.moralis.io/web3-data-api/evm/reference/get-token-price?address=0xe9e7CEA3DedcA5984780Bafc599bD69ADd087D56&chain=bsc&include=percent_change&exchange=pancakeswapv2.

Hope this helps!

Cheers~

You can follow this tutorial to implement the API to get token price either in Python or JS/TS https://docs.moralis.io/web3-data-api/evm/how-to-get-the-price-of-an-erc20-token

P.S. I work at Moralis

Answer (score 0):

To get price data from PancakeSwap in a React application, you can use various methods, including fetching data from an API or interacting directly with the blockchain using a library like Web3.js. Below, I'll provide an example using Web3.js to fetch price data for a token pair from PancakeSwap on the Binance Smart Chain (BSC).

Please note that you'll need to set up a Web3.js environment and have access to the BSC network to interact with Pancake Swap's smart contracts. You can also use a library like web3-react to simplify Web3 integration in your React app.

Comment: Examples of how to do the things you describe would make your answer stronger.